# Set dropdown value based on what is selected in another dropdown using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have couple of drop downs whose values are readily available as below.

Dropdown 1:

```
<select id="a">
  <option value="1">Bike</option>
  <option value="2">Car</option>
  <option value="3">Bus</option>
  <option value="4">Cycle</option>
  <option value="5">Wagon</option>
</select>
```

Dropdown 2:

```
<select id="b">
  <option value="1">2 wheel</option>
  <option value="2">4 wheel</option>
  <option value="3">6 wheel</option>
</select>
```

I need to change second dropdown value based on the selected value from first dropdown. For example:

- If Bike or Cycle is selected from dropdown 1, 2 wheel should be auto selected
- If Car or Wagon is selected, 4 wheel should be auto selected.

Only option available for me is to use JavaScript. I tried like below, but it isn't working. Please help pointing out what am I missing/doing incorrect.

HTML:

```
<select id="a" onchange="change();">
  <option value="1">Bike</option>
  <option value="2">Car</option>
  <option value="3">Bus</option>
  <option value="4">Cycle</option>
  <option value="5">Wagon</option>
</select>
<select id="b">
  <option value="1">2 wheel</option>
  <option value="2">4 wheel</option>
  <option value="3">6 wheel</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function change() {
if (document.getElementById('a').value == '1')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '1';
else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '2')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '2';
else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '3')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '3';
else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '4')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '1';
else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '5')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '2';
};
```

EDIT: To be more specfic about what I need, I edited the example above.

Comment: @mplungjan: Please see my edit in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your explanation, I would go with this:

```js
window.onload=function() { 
  document.getElementById("a").onchange=function() {
    document.getElementById("b").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-sync"); 
  }
  document.getElementById("a").onchange(); // trigger when loading
}
```

```html
<select id="a">
  <option value="1" data-sync="1">Bike</option>
  <option value="2" data-sync="2" selected>Car</option>
  <option value="3" data-sync="3">Bus</option>
  <option value="4" data-sync="1">Cycle</option>
  <option value="5" data-sync="2">Wagon</option>
</select>
<select id="b">
  <option value="1">2 wheel</option>
  <option value="2">4 wheel</option>
  <option value="3">6 wheel</option>
</select>
```

Actually your code works too - perhaps your browser does not like the function name `change`

```js
function change() {
  if (document.getElementById('a').value == '1')
    document.getElementById("b").value = '1';
  else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '2')
    document.getElementById("b").value = '2';
  else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '3')
    document.getElementById("b").value = '3';
  else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '4')
    document.getElementById("b").value = '1';
  else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '5')
    document.getElementById("b").value = '2';
};
```

```html
<select id="a" onchange="change();">
  <option value="1">Bike</option>
  <option value="2">Car</option>
  <option value="3">Bus</option>
  <option value="4">Cycle</option>
  <option value="5">Wagon</option>
</select>
<select id="b">
  <option value="1">2 wheel</option>
  <option value="2">4 wheel</option>
  <option value="3">6 wheel</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I will try your solution. For some reason, my code isn't working.

Comment: I managed to make both solutions work. Earlier I was passing the 'Id' as parameter to the function which did not work. After referencing the id directly in document.getElementById, it worked. Thanks!