# Set dropdown value based on what is selected in another dropdown using Javascript, and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html

I see that answer

[Set dropdown value based on what is selected in another dropdown using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203800)

And I want make the other hand too. When select an element on select id=b reset the select on id=a, example

select "another option 1" and the id=a set to "---"

why is not working?

HTML:

```
<select id="a" onchange="changedrop();">
  <option value="1">---</option>
  <option value="2">option 1</option>
  <option value="3">option 2</option>
  <option value="4">option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="b" onchange="changedrop();">>
  <option value="1">---</option>
  <option value="2">another option 1</option>
  <option value="3">another option 2</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function changedrop() {
  if (document.getElementById('a').value == '1')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '1';
  else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '2')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '1';
  else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '3')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '1';
  else if (document.getElementById('a').value == '4')
  document.getElementById("b").value = '1';
  else if (document.getElementById('b').value == '1')
  document.getElementById("a").value = '1';
  else if (document.getElementById('b').value == '2')
  document.getElementById("a").value = '1';
  else if (document.getElementById('b').value == '3')
  document.getElementById("a").value = '1';
};
```

Comment: Because you only attached the function to one of the selects? `a` knows what to do on a change, but how could `b` know to do the same?

Comment: Just a quick tip, you don't need a whole new else if statement if the outcome is the same, simply add "||" which will do the code if one condition is true, OR if the next one is, so like this document.getElementById('a').value == '2' || document.getElementById('a').value == '3' || document.getElementById('a').value == '4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to listen to the `onchange` event on both `select` elements.

```js
function changeDropA() {
  var a = document.getElementById('a');
  var b = document.getElementById("b");
  
  if (a.value == '1')
    b.value = '1';
  else if (a.value == '2')
    b.value = '1';
  else if (a.value == '3')
    b.value = '1';
  else if (a.value == '4')
    b.value = '1';
};

function changeDropB() {
  var a = document.getElementById('a');
  var b = document.getElementById("b");

  if (b.value == '1')
    a.value = '1';
  else if (b.value == '2')
    a.value = '1';
  else if (b.value == '3')
    a.value = '1';
}

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('change', changeDropA);
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('change', changeDropB);
```

```html
<select id="a">
  <option value="1">---</option>
  <option value="2">option 1</option>
  <option value="3">option 2</option>
  <option value="4">option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="b">
  <option value="1">---</option>
  <option value="2">another option 1</option>
  <option value="3">another option 2</option>
</select>
```